# How heavy is gesString(R.string constants), context tight coupling and constant classes

Tags: java, android, xml, oop

I am developing for android and I have faced with this problem a lot of times.
Let me explain.
Android provides a great way not to hardcode values directly in the code but store them in xml file.
Android app in terms of `DVM` is instance of `DVM`, but from java perspective it is `Application` class the topmost object that exists in the memory during the application lifetime or even any app component like activity,service, etc.
So this object can be treated as app instance.
AFAIK this application object has main context, the same as we sometimes getting with `getApplicationContext`.
Context class is the kind of God Object that stores a lot different things . We are interested now in resources from xml files.
I have tried to find the implementation of `getString` or other method for getting resources, but AFAIK they are native, so I gave up,cause of lack of time.
I often work with android `SMALI(dissasembly)`,but have never paid attention to this it looks like

```
.line 29
    const v0, 0x7f07005e

    invoke-virtual {p0, v0}, Landroid/content/Context;->getString(I)Ljava/lang/String;
```

This ID(0x7f07005e in our case) is mapped to `public.xml` file inside apk archive.

So my **first** question is what happens under the hood of `getString` method, is it heavy, where string constants from string.xml are stored in memory or still in xml file in runtime it parses this values from xml file. Or these values are stored somewhere in memory ?

And the **second** question is more about best practices and architecture. 
If I need to get constant from string.xml file where I have no access to the context, I have no choice other than pass them to the place where I need them after getting them somewhere else where I have context or use constant classes.
In case of getting constants from string.xml we need access to the context object, so in this case we are tying classes that actually don't need context with application only to get a pair of constants.
Other approach is considered to be bad practice is `Constant classes`.
Even if use them, you need to change your code each time something some value has been changed, but what if use something combined from two approaches like this.

```
public class MyWheelConstants {
    public static String CONSTANT_1;
    public static String CONSTANT_2;

    public static void init(Context context) {
        CONSTANT_1 = context.getString(R.string.constant1);
        CONSTANT_2 = context.getString(R.string.constant2);
    }
}
```

And for example move this into the `Application` class in `onCreate` method, we are not tied in this case , but this should be reimplemented in singletone or any other way to make constants final.

Please share your thoughts and advice.
Thx in advance.

Comment: `Context` instances are quite easy to access from  `Fragment`, `Activity` and even `View` subclasses (these are all quite equal if you just need to call getResources()). In my experience it has never been an issue. Other classes can store `Context`s too with no trouble (but some attention). I believe your proposed approach is just doubling what we already have - I don't think XML values resources are parsed at runtime.